# android.media.audiofx.Equalizer methods don't work in real-time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a media file that must be played with `MediaPlayer` class.

So, first I initialize a MediaPlayer variable:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.queen);
```

Then I'm creating an equalizer:

```
eq = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
eq.setEnabled(true);
```

After that, during playing I want to move seek bars to change my band levels in real time. For example as so:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    switch (seekBar.getId()){
    case R.id.eqBar1:
        eq.setBandLevel((short) 0, (short)(eq1Seek.getProgress() - minRange));
        break;
```

... and so on for all the bands. The application works correctly, no errors occured, but there is no effect when manipulation with Seek Bars.

So, why it doesn't work? How it is possible to apply equalizer parameters changes during playing?

Thanks in advance!

In this part of code:

```
    case R.id.eqBar1:
        eq.setBandLevel((short) 0, (short)(eq1Seek.getProgress() - minRange));
        bndText.setText(String.valueOf(eq.hasControl()));
        bndText.setText(bndText.getText() + " " + String.valueOf(eq.setEnabled(true)));
        break;
```

`hasControl()` returns `true` and `setEnabled` returns `0` (success) but the equalizer seems not  be applied - I don't hear any difference when moving `seekbars` (((

Comment: You should check the return-value of [`setEnabled(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) and use [`hasControl()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#hasControl%28%29) to see if actually *have* control.

Comment: Lukas, I have such construction in the same switch block: case R.id.playBar:mediaPlayer.seekTo(playSeek.getProgress());break; -  and it works!

Comment: That uses the MediaPlayer, not the Equalizer...

Comment: @LukasKnuth
I get returned value of -5 from setEnabled() function. what does that mean? note that after I use setBandLevel() function . the function executed successfully but the sound doesn't changed!! please help me

Comment: @MalekTubaisaht You should ask this as a question. My original comment is now 7 years old, I'm not sure any of this still applies to "modern" Andriod.